# Is there a command to find out the available memory in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, memory

I am looking for a command that returns the available physical memory in Windows. I tried "systeminfo" but it takes too long and returns a lot of unnessesary information for me. If there is not any command for this what would be the best way to obtain it in a different way using command prompt?

Comment: For a laugh you can type `mem` in a `cmd` shell, but that won't get you very far :-)

Comment: What version of windows?

Comment: @Mat 941kB in XMS memory, ha ha :-D

Answer (score 50, accepted):

It takes some time (around 10 seconds for me) but the following command will do it:

```
systeminfo |find "Available Physical Memory"
```

Comment: Note that this depends on your OS language. My above example works for English OSes. For example, for a Turkish OS, the following command line should be used: `systeminfo |find "Kullanılabilir Fiziksel Bellek"`

Comment: [This](http://i.imgur.com/QNe1P.png) is an example from my PC showing a screeny of the outcome.

Comment: if you just 'find "Memory"' instead it gives a quick overview of all of it. Total, Available, Virtual: Available, Virtual: In Use

Comment: Way too slow... highly not recommended. To show memory it needs to scan entire system.

Answer (score 21):

This will do it without taking 10 secs. Try this:

For Total Physical Memory

```
wmic ComputerSystem get TotalPhysicalMemory
```

For Available Physical Memory:

```
wmic OS get FreePhysicalMemory
```

Comment: Note that the values returned are in kilobytes

Comment: It looks like TotalPhysicalMemory returns bytes, but FreePhysicalMemory returns kilobytes.. Which is a pretty big mindf*ck

Comment: The 'wmic' command-line tool is _deprecated_ as of Windows 10 version 21H1
[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/wmic)

Answer (score 12):

Well if you are on Windows 7, you can use this at the powershell prompt:

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMemory |  Measure-Object Capacity -Sum).sum
```

Or if you want a nice pretty how many gigs is it:

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_PhysicalMemory |  Measure-Object Capacity -Sum).sum/1GB
```

Or if you are on an older version of windows (or W7 for that matter) at the command prompt:

```
wmic memorychip get capacity
```

Comment: It's worth noting that whilst `msinfo32` is usable by non-administrators for this purpose, `wmic` is not.

Comment: I think that might be a policy issue. I just ran the wmic command just fine as a non-admin.

Comment: No, it's not a policy issue.  It fails on non-domain machines as well.  The message that you'll see as a non-administrator is `Only the administrator group members can use WMIC.EXE.`.

Comment: Well, I'm not an admin and I did not see that message. Instead I saw the capacity of the two memory sticks installed on that machine.

Comment: Just checked to be sure and the user ID I was logged in with is not a member of the local Administrators group, nor is it a member of any of the AD groups that are local admins.

Comment: +1 because this command worked for me too (and I didn't have to be logged in as an Administrator either, although this really isn't an issue anyway because the original questioner didn't specify it as a requirement).

Answer (score 6):

How about

```
typeperf "\Memory\Available Bytes"
```

in cmd or powershell prompt? You can find other monitoring instances with the command

```
typeperf -qx "\Memory"
```

Comment: Note that the performance counter names are language dependent. Therefore on a non-english system the presented commands will fail.

Answer (score 3):

You already know about `systeminfo`, as per the question.  And as Mat noted in a comment, the `mem` command doesn't tell you what you want to know.

JP Software's TCC/LE has [the built-in `MEMORY` command](http://jpsoft.com./help/memory.htm), which operates thus:

```
[C:\]memory

           30 % Memory load

  3,471,441,920 bytes total physical RAM
  2,428,456,960 bytes available physical RAM

  5,440,962,560 bytes total page file
  4,505,726,976 bytes available page file

  2,147,352,576 bytes total virtual RAM
  2,053,435,392 bytes available virtual RAM

        262,144 characters total alias
        262,143 characters free

         20,480 characters total history

[C:\]
```

It also has [the `@WINMEMORY[]` variable function](http://jpsoft.com./help/f_winmemory.htm), which can be used in various ways:

```
[C:\]echo There are %@COMMA[%@WINMEMORY[2]] available bytes physical RAM.
There are 2,456,285,184 available bytes physical RAM.

[C:\]
```

Bundled with Windows comes the `msinfo32` command, whose output can be restricted more narrowly than that of `systeminfo`:

```
msinfo32 /categories +systemsummary
```

There are a whole load of other utilities, from various people, that can report the same information.